# Stored procedure giving "discount" based on X number of months from todays date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dateadd

So my problem is that I have to make a procedure that will multiply all prices in my product table with 0.8 if the product haven't sold for X number of months.

At the moment I can't seem to get any further than this:

```
GO
CREATE PROC newprice(@numberofmonth int)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @today datetime
SET @today = GetDate()
SELECT product.productid, product.name 
FROM orders JOIN orderitem on orderitem.orderid = orders.orderid
            JOIN product on product.productid = orderitem.productid
WHERE orders.orderdate > (SELECT DATEADD(month, -@numberofmonth, @today))

UPDATE product set price = price * 0.8 where  
END
```

Hope everything is transparent enough to read and understand without any further description. I'm working with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not understand your problem completly.i just assume your need look this

```
    GO CREATE PROC newprice(@numberofmonth int) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @today datetime 
SET @today = GetDate() 
UPDATE product set price = price * 0.8 FROM orders JOIN orderitem on orderitem.orderid = orders.orderid JOIN product on product.productid = orderitem.productid WHERE orders.orderdate >
(SELECT DATEADD(month, -@numberofmonth, @today))   
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE newprice(@numberofmonth int)
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE product
SET price = price * 0.8
FROM  product 
JOIN orderitem on product.productid = orderitem.productid
JOIN orders on orderitem.orderid = orders.orderid
WHERE orders.orderdate > (DATEADD(month, -@numberofmonth, GETDATE()))

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it makes what you need:

```
DECLARE @today datetime
SET @today = GetDate()

Select * FROM product
--UPDATE product SET price = price * 0.8 
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT product.productid, product.name 
    FROM orders 
    INNER JOIN orderitem on orderitem.orderid = orders.orderid
    WHERE orders.orderdate > (SELECT DATEADD(month, -@numberofmonth, @today)))
```